# Is it possible to get user input in Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm developing a Windows Service in C#.  One of my requirements is to get some user input: to present some options and let them select one; based on their choice, the service should  perform an associated operation.  Is it possible to get user input in a Windows Service, with C#?

Answer (score 3):

No, a Windows Service is not designed for that.  You would need to use a desktop or web application.  If there is a good reason to use a service, you would need to create an application and have it send or communicate the input to the service.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a separate application that manages the options in a database, a user can update this database in which the service also connects to, depending on these values the service should act accordingly

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You should create another windows app (for example winforms or WPF) and communicate with service and send user input. You can do communication via WCF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ServiceBroker to Queue Userinput messages and dump the result in another Queue against the UserId or unique user key.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said this is not possible. A Windows service, as the name implies is a Service. If you want to send data to a Windows Service, you can either do so through the ServiceController Class (from another application) or if you're feeling particularly adventurous though WCF.

Why are you developing this as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to get inputs from mouse and keyboard from windows service. This does not mean that, we can directly interact with the windows service. Service code can read the last keyboard input and mouse position and other events. for example, service can read the current mouse position using `Cursor.Position` property.