# Checking if user uses mouse (move, click, scroll) or keyboard (press a key) in Windows Service application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have learned C#, and I started to learn creating Windows Service application. I am quite new, nevertheless I try everyday spending lots of hours learning how to create Windows Service application.

My service app should check if user of computer uses mouse (move, click, scroll) or keyboard (press a key).

If user does so, the computer will do a specific action. I know how to check this conditions in Windows Forms, but implementation in Windows Service is still mystery for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get user input in Windows Service C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702160/is-it-possible-to-get-user-input-in-windows-service-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you looking to monitor all actions a user undertakes with their mouse and keyboard? What is the overall purpose of such a service?

Comment: @halfer Yes, i just want to check if user uses computer during amount of time. If not, after this time it will be turned off, so that increase the level of economy of energy

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. There is no GUI attached to a Windows Service, so you'll have to pick up those events from your Windows Forms project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702160/is-it-possible-to-get-user-input-in-windows-service-c-sharp) article for more information.